# 8-Bit / Small Zephyr RTOS Microcontrollers?

Tags: freertos, rtos

I have not kept up with microcontrollers over the last few years, and am teaching a new EE out of college practical firmware on devices.  When I learned how to write firmware, I started with a PIC16 (baremetal), did a commercial projects on antique 8051 (bare metal), and then learned TI RTOS (and now don't do any development!).

I am going to teach them PIC16 (baremetal) and I wanted to teach them a modern RTOS, and I was thinking Zephyr instead of FreeRTOS.

Is there any non-ARM / 8 bit microcontrollers that support Zephyr and have an easy Windows based IDE, kind of like MPLab for PIC?   I hate to toss a newbie into the ARM dynamic where you basically don't talk about registers anymore and it's just drivers and RTOS.

TI RTOS, which I know, you basically just use a default project, spin up some tasks, set up your IO pins, and away you go....  I'm trying to find some middle ground if possible for education sake.

Comment: Zephyr is the "official" "standard" RTOS of RISC-V, and this is the trend now.

Comment: RISC-V, that is some exotic stuff!  Do you have  any idea in RISC-V land, what tracks to like a Cortex-M0?

Comment: As I said, RISC-V is the trend today and is rapidly moving to mainstream. I can tell you that some *major* players of the semiconductor industry are moving from ARM to RISC-V

Comment: But there's no 8-bit support for Zephyr. Did you look at the list of supported MCUs on website? Smallest are ARM Cortex-M0 devices. And why do you want to teach the junior something like the PIC16 and it's registers which the junior will never use? You can use registers on ARMs and you have to if you want to modify the drivers to do what you want if they don't suit to what you want. Just because you had to ski to school during winter and summer, uphill both ways, let the junior have a fresh start with what's relevant. Basically, what you are asking is what to teach to a junior?

Comment: PS.  I'm not that old....! Can you imagine trying to wrap your head around Timers & Interrupts on an ARM and the build tools the first time around?  Seriously, we are going from an Arduino, to a PIC16, and then I'm trying to not dump them to this: https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/arm-cortex-m-exceptions-and-nvic  -- the ARM complexity is massively exponential [which is why you use drivers and don't ask questions!].

Comment: @Justme -- nope, totally don't need help with the curriculum.  Just seeing if there any other lightweight processor besides ARMs on Zephyr with pretty fleshed out modern IDEs / build chains, etc.

Comment: My note to order: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/2.7.0/boards/arm/stm32f0_disco/doc/index.html

Comment: @Leroy105 I agree that's the way to go these days. Some mouse clicking and you have a complete project skeleton running RTOS and blinking LED task on a GHz scale multi core MCU in minutes using the vendor drivers. Hard to beat that when you need to kickstart a new project quickly. I still feel what you are asking may lead to opinion-based answers of what to learn/buy.

Comment: @Justme *why do you want to teach the junior something like the PIC16 and it's registers which the junior will never use?* I don't want to sideline into what should be taught and how, as that's the OP's concern and area of expertise, not ours, but: learning within restrictions is always infinitely better, learning without is poor. Boxed-in 8-bit or PIC systems, slow with low memory and problem areas everywhere, are just what newcomers should start learning bare-metal programming on. It's a philosophy this site says to newcomers all the time: understand how it works, the trade-offs, the basics.

Comment: The stark simplicity of typical 8-bit processors is an advantage, in learning though you can still do bare metal C programming on an ARM, the charm fades when you need USB or Ethernet. I’m not sure running into, say, cache issues improves the learning experience.

Comment: Too bad this was closed;  see: https://www.chibios.org/dokuwiki/doku.php

Answer (score 3):

As a middle-ground alternative, I'd suggest using a real-time embedded framework that is lighter than an RTOS, and exposes a much smaller API.

I'm talking about hierarchical state machines. For many applications with a single core on a small microcontroller, a full RTOS is overkill. What's needed instead is a way to handle various inputs and events in real time, and state machines are great for that.

There's at least one very good, well documented and thought out framework that implemented hierarchical state machines on a variety of systems, including MCUs. It's a collection of "mini" frameworks by [Quantum Leaps](https://www.state-machine.com/).

Comment: Thanks!  Great suggestion.

Comment: @Leroy105 They have simple tutorials to start with. It is rather important to understand the underlying concepts of hierarchical state machines, since that's not most people are used to. It's a rather useful formalism, and works great in practice.

Comment: Quantum Leaps youtube channel was a great learning resource for me.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach I've taken in the past, and is very simple to both create and write as well as explain, is a cooperative scheduler. Adding a per-thread message is trivial and also useful, but not necessary.

The primary function that needs to be taught and used is *switch()*, which simply allows underlying code to switch stacks and return from some other *switch()* call in a different thread. It's not complicated.

One less-discussed advantage in cooperative systems is that you can use all the usual libraries without worrying they may have static lifetime working variables that may be stomped on if you were operating with a pre-emptive scheduler. The reason is simple: the only way another thread starts up is with the *switch()* call and you cannot be using a library routine when you do that. So it's pretty clean and easy.

Also, fewer registers need to be saved and restored between switching as the C language (if you use it instead of assembly) has a limited number of *preserve* registers across calls with many *scratch* registers that can be erased during the switch() call.

A very simple system takes about a day or two to write (for me) in C and ASM, depending on how much I want to shovel into it (semaphores, messages, background threads, etc.) But the essentials (keep in mind that as I write this I'm simultaneously thinking about functions in the C language or else functions in ASM -- doesn't really matter but it is easier to conceptualize the following and for me to write about it below if thinking in C) are:

- *pcreate()*: Allows the creation of a new thread. The function address is specified as the first parameter, either the stack size (if allocating from heap) or the address of the thread's stack memory (otherwise) is the second parameter, and the list of parameters to pass when starting the thread are the remaining parameters to this function.
- *pswitch()*: No parameters. However, if you want to support allowing a direct switch to another thread by naming them or otherwise providing an identifier, then that's also fine. In that case, there would be that ID as a parameter.
- *pinit()*: Called by the single-thread start code (in C, this is main().) Probably a good idea to have this. It just sets things up (maximum number of threads, for example) and ensures that *main()* is set up as the current (and only) thread. Performs any necessary interrupt hooking, semaphore queues, or other details, as needed. When *main()* (or the starting ASM code) returns at the end, the entire system is automatically torn down. So there's no necessity for a complementary *pshutdown()* function.

That's pretty much it. All threads are automatically killed when they return from their initiating function (the address that is passed into *pcreate()*.)

I usually include these:

- *pid()*: Reports a special PID for the running thread. This allows the thread to pass along or send a message to another thread with this ID. It also allows a thread to kill another thread if it has its PID.
- *pkill()*: Allows a thread to kill another thread. Also works to kill itself, if desired.
- *psleep()*: Allows a thread to either go to sleep permanently (until awoken) or to specify a time parameter after which it is moved from the sleep queue to the run queue. (In this case, a timer interrupt needs to be hooked and used, along with a delta-queue structure for the sleep queue itself.)
- *pawaken()*: Allows another thread to awaken a thread that is on the sleep queue if it has the PID for it.
- *psendmessage()*: Allows a thread to send a message to another thread (or itself, I suppose.) Requires the PID and the message. A simple design would only allow an integer message (easy to implement.) But if an address is allowed, then any kind of arbitrary structure would work, instead.
- *pgetmessage()*: Allows a thread to examine its incoming message and, if present, to retrieve it. Again, to keep things really simple and quick to implement, just allow one message. If a second message is sent to the same thread, over-write the message with the newer one. But it's not difficult to implement message queues. So that's another option here. (This function can return status to allow the caller to determine if there even was a message, of course.)

If the C language is being used, it can be useful to support thread-local stack unwinds via *setjmp()* and *longjmp()*. This also isn't hard. But it may not be necessary in your case.

The main point in all the above is to simply say that you can keep the operating system quite simple to teach, learn, and use by just taking a day or two to write one. They are NOT at all hard to do.

I was working with a client some years ago and one of their employees (an embedded programmer who knew both C and ASM) was struggling with a problem that really needed threads to help simplify it and make it more maintainable. I spent about 2 hours teaching him how to create a little array to store the thread stacks and how to create functions like those above.

It was my pleasure when he came running into my (temporary) office the very next afternoon telling me that he'd done it and it was working and he was very, very excited about it. He brought me over to see what he'd done and it was already integrated into the code he'd been working on for many years beforehand. Worked perfectly!

It's really that easy.

(Note: the above is a little more C-centric than I'd like. But it made it easier to write it and I am feeling lazy, today. With a little imagination, I'm sure that you can re-orient yourself to a design that would be ASM-only, if that's your goal. It is all the same semantics. Just slightly different syntax.)

Of course, whether or not this approach is attractive will depend on your teaching goals. Only you can speak to that.

Comment: It's been a bit Jon!  We should catch up someday soon.  (Actually a little bit slow in the dead middle of July, so I'm doing some training in house here!).

Comment: @Leroy105 Assuming I'm recognizing the personality and response here then it has been a long time! (I figured you'd have been pretty busy with the gangbusters testing business stuff.) As a side project (no money, just pleasure) I'm re-creating the HP 2000F TSB on the MSP430FR5994, right now.

Comment: A few years after the HP 2000F was the desktop HP9825. I had to create an RTOS out of HP BASIC to remote control over 100 channels of ADC/DAC and 96 power relay states with a 9600 baud link between two HP9825's and an IO multiprogrammer with cyclic scan of all results dumped on a smart terminal using DMA and used keycodes for 1 key commands for this SCADA "calculator".

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I'll have a working 2000F TSB sooner than later. Work in progress, right now. If you are interested in helping decide what features are important for embedded work -- let me know. I'm developing the assembly code now. I'll take advantage of any good input I can get. :)